# Google line chart width and hover issue

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, google-visualization

The chart below has a lot of data and it doesnt display as I want.

[image: Chart detail]

To try displaying it better i used `width: chartData.getNumberOfRows() * 90` on chart options, now it looks like this:

[image: Chart detail 2]

Notice the overflow on the right side, to solve that I used

```
 overflow-x: scroll; 
 overflow-y: hidden;
```

on the parent element of the chart, the wrapping div. Now it looks like this:

[image: Chart detail 3]

But there is a problem when hovering over the points in the chart:

[image: Chart detail 4]

If I hover after its max natural width, It just does that.

**Is there any way to solve the hovering?**

**There is also a problem when there are multiple lines that have same quantity on a day, when I hover on that point, it only shows the data of 1 line, not all. I expect something like this:**

[image: Chart detail 5]

Comment: to show all categories on the tooltip, set `focusTarget: 'category'` in the chart options